# python3 tkinter: can I get ragged grids without aligned columns?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, geometry

I'm writing a GUI in python, and using tkinter. I'm having trouble settling on an approach and need guidance.

Background: there's a server (not a webserver) that wants to present a lot of information to users, and let them edit some of it. It needs to send down information that a (relatvely) dumb python client uses to fill the window. Read only fields are Labels. The fields are generally single line Entry widgets, but some are multiline Text. There are some buttons, checkboxes and dropdowns. Asynchronously, the server can also update widgets, add them and remove them. In some cases, there are tables presented, to which the user needs to be able to add and remove rows.

The real problem is, the layout is dense and chaotic. The first row might contain 3 dropdown fields. The next might be 20 short Labels. The next might be a single long Entry field, and then I might want two tables (of different lengths) side by side,and then etc.. Based on user input of external factors, widgets, rows or entire tables might have to be dyamically added, or vanish.

I considered Grid, but it's unusable. A row with a single, long entry widgit in it, makes the first column wide and thereby pushes 12 of the 13 columns in the next row right off the window.

I considered Place, but this app will run on 3 different operating systems and users will be able to select their own fonts, so I'll never get the positions right. If there was some way to ask a widget how big it was, I'd happily use that to compute my own layouts in pixels, but it's apparently impossible to ask the size of a widget until AFTER it's been laid out by a geometry manager, which of course is too late.

So what I think I'm left with is Pack, where each row is its own frame, and some of those rows have tables (grids) in them. But I'm concerned that that means lots and lots of frames to render, and some of the users are on old, slow hardware. Plus...  it looks just plain complex.

Am I missing a better way? Grid would be fine if I could convince it to stop trying to make columns line up. Place would be crunchy, but ok, if I could get the size of each widget in advance. Is placing within a lot of frames really the best I have?

Comment: _"...But I'm concerned that that means lots and lots of frames to render"_ - unless you have literally thousands of rows, performance isn't going to be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, there's no better way; and the frame count isn't high enough to cause performance problems; so generating a frame per row is what works.